# My App is giving the "Register Error 1" - why so?

Tags: java, android, json

i am trying to write a class that would collect data from the registration form and send it to an online database, i am doing that through volley, but i keep getting the same error "Registration Error 1", I already checking my database connection and the PHP Registration code and it is okay. i think the problem is from this class. The error now has changed. Now i am getting a "Registration Error 2"

```
private void Register () {
    loading.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    signUpBtn.setVisibility (View.GONE);

    final String firstName = this.firstName.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    final String lastName = this.lastName.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    final String userEmail = this.userEmail.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    final String userPassword = this.userPassword.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    final String name = firstName + " " + lastName;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest (Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST,
            new Response.Listener<String> () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse (String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString ("success");

                        if (success.equals ("1")) {
                            Toast.makeText (Registration.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        }
                    } catch(JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                        Toast.makeText (Registration.this, "Registration Error 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                        loading.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                        signUpBtn.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener () {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText (Registration.this, "Registration Error 2!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    loading.setVisibility (View.GONE);
                    signUpBtn.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams () throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<> ();
            params.put ("name", name);
            params.put ("userEmail", userEmail);
            params.put ("userPassword", userPassword);

            return super.getParams ();
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue (this);
    requestQueue.add (stringRequest);
}
```

i checked the logcat and this is what i am getting. 
2019-09-23 12:05:46.354 26011-26011/com.scoutfrika.scoutfrika W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

2019-09-23 12:05:48.514 26011-26011/com.scoutfrika.scoutfrika W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

2019-09-23 12:05:51.422 26011-26011/com.scoutfrika.scoutfrika W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

2019-09-23 12:05:52.032 26011-26011/com.scoutfrika.scoutfrika W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
2019-09-23 12:05:56.446 1912-26100/? E/FA: Name must consist of letters, digits or _ (underscores). Type, name: event, isNetworkConnected:false

2019-09-23 12:05:56.449 1912-26100/? E/FA: Invalid public event name. Event will not be logged (FE): isNetworkConnected:false

2019-09-23 12:05:57.206 26011-26011/com.scoutfrika.scoutfrika W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

2019-09-23 12:05:59.335 1912-26100/? E/FA: Name must consist of letters, digits or _ (underscores). Type, name: event, isNetworkConnected:false

2019-09-23 12:05:59.337 1912-26100/? E/FA: Invalid public event name. Event will not be logged (FE): isNetworkConnected:false

Comment: use `Log.e("TAG", "Registration Error 1 "+e.toString())` in your `catch` block to print your `exception` in the console. and post it with your question.

Comment: what does `e.printStackTrace ();` print in logs?

Answer (score 0):

when this error appears ,you should see your logcat to find JSONException and make sure which line caused this.if the resopnse string is correct Json,maybe you get String by wrong key